# IOS Real Device Failing to Connect to HTTPS Server on AWS

Tags: javascript, ios, amazon-web-services, react-native, react-native-ios

I have been building an app using React Native and up until now been doing everything locally. I need to finish development with a real device as the final features cannot be done locally. I am very new to IOS and React Native. I created a functioning EC2 instance and I established an https certificate to the load balancer. I am able to connect via Postman but when I try to launch the app and login with the real device I get the following error:

```
Task <0E556862-E230-40C9-B070-C0C36B158718>.<5> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “web-server-load-balancer-staging-815978603.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=(
    "<cert(0x10b044200) s: www.moder8.net i: Amazon>",
    "<cert(0x10b044a00) s: Amazon i: Amazon Root CA 1>",
    "<cert(0x10b045200) s: Amazon Root CA 1 i: Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2>",
    "<cert(0x10b045a00) s: Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2 i: Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority>"
), NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://web-server-load-balancer-staging-815978603.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/auth/login, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://web-server-load-balancer-staging-815978603.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/auth/login, NSUnderlyingError=0x28246e820 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1202 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: 0x28182f0f0>, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9843, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9843, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=(
    "<cert(0x10b044200) s: www.moder8.net i: Amazon>",
    "<cert(0x10b044a00) s: Amazon i: Amazon Root CA 1>",
    "<cert(0x10b045200) s: Amazon Root CA 1 i: Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2>",
    "<cert(0x10b045a00) s: Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2 i: Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority>"
```

***What I have tried:***

I wish I could say I have tried code related changes but since this is all new to me my only recourse was googling and unfortunately most of what I have found is related to developers attempting to connect locally with the real device as the device wants to use https. I am using https so it confuses me as to why it has this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your load balancer is presenting the certificate for `www.moder8.net`, but you're accessing it via `web-server-load-balancer-staging-815978603.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com`, so the domain names don't match.

You need to either change the load balancer to serve a certificate that matches the domain, or set up DNS on your domain to go to your load balancer.